# Parsing lines from a script

Tags: python, parsing

I need to read lines from a file representing server tasks. The lines are composed of several pairs some of which are duplicated. I need to parse them, eliminate the duplicates and divide them in groups of 2 for better execution. This is how aline looks like:

```
'task1'->3124, 'task2'->7743, 'task1'->3124, 'task3'->3456, 'task4'->23984
```

I want to obtain:

```
task1 task2
task3 task4
```

I am pretty new to Python (only C experience) and would like some help using more pythonic functions for my code. This is my current code(still incomplete but already with errors):

```
def findgroups(s):
    group=[]
    n=[]
    for i in range(len(s)):
        group.append(s[i])        
        if s[i]==',':
            n.append(group)
            group=[]
    return n

def finduniques(groups):
    unique=[]
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        if groups.count(groups[i])==1:
            unique.append(groups[i])
    return unique

def makegroups(groups):
    group1=[]
    group2=[]
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        if i%2==0:
            group1.append(groups[i])
        if i%2==1:
            group2.append(groups[i])

def printgroups(group1, group2):
    for i in range(len(group1)):
        for j in range(len(group2)):
            if i==j:
                print group1[0],group2[0]


line = "'task1'->3124, 'task2'->7743, 'task1'->3124, 'task3'->3456, 'task4'->23984"
groups = find_groups(line)
uniques = find_uniques(groups)
pairs = makegroups(uniques)
print printgroups(pairs)
```

Comment: First rule: Don't try to write C in Python. Instead of `for i in len(groups): do_something_with(groups[i])`, you do `for group in groups: do_something_with(group)`

Comment: what are other names for taks ? it is only of the format taskn , n being an integer.

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter in the final output?

Comment: sorry that's a test I was doing with python dictionaries.

Comment: @John, ok now? Does you code work with the dict or without the dict?

Comment: task is a string with arbitrary format and the other number is an integer. The integer can be ignored, I just want to execute the tasks.

Comment: with the dict I find a problem that group[0] raises an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
import re
from itertools import izip_longest

line = "'task1'->3124, 'task2'->7743, 'task1'->3124, 'task3'->3456, 'task4'->23984"
tasks = set(re.findall("'(.*?)'->\d+", line))
for t1, t2 in izip_longest(*[iter(tasks)] * 2, fillvalue=''):
    print t1, t2
# task1 task2
# task3 task4
```

- Find everything inside single quotes that's followed by `->` and some numbers
- Put into a set to eliminate duplicates
- Group into twos and where there's an odd one, leave a blank string `''`

Answer (score 1):

This accomplishes what you want:

```
>>> import ast

>>> s = "'task1'->3124, 'task2'->7743, 'task1'->3124, 'task3'->3456, 'task4'->23984"
>>> d = ast.literal_eval('{' + s.replace('->', ':') + '}')
{'task1': 3124, 'task2': 7743, 'task3': 3456, 'task4': 23984}

>>> it = iter(d) 
>>> for first, second in zip(it, it):
        print first, second
task1 task2
task3 task4
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to python, you could simply do the following

```
list(set([l.split('->')[0][1:-1] for l in line.split(', ')]))
```

This will return following for your input example

```
['task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4']
```

### Explanation:

- split

  > > This will splits the string by given chars. Here ',' and ' ', so this will return all the pairs
- l.split('->')[0]

  > > This will split the pair and pick task name with quotes
- l.split('->')[0][1:-1]

  > > This will pick the part of task name from 1 to len-1 characters, this is to remove quotes.
- set

  > > This will convert the list into set of unique elements.
- list

  > > convert the set back to a list